# How to pass data dynamically to lightning-tree-grid

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

In my LWC, I am following [LWC example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/example) to implement lightning-tree-grid within lightning-layout-item as accordions.

I have the data in the JSON format as below:

```
"contents":[
              {
                 "location":"Phoenix, AZ",
                 "url":"www........com",
                 "type":"City"
              },
              .
              .
              .
           ]
```

I have parsed the data and stored in an array for passing to lightning-tree-grid.

The columns for the grid is as follows:

```
const Grid_Cols = [
        {type: 'text', fieldName: 'locations',label: 'Locations',hideDefaultActions: true,},
        {type: 'url', fieldName: 'URLs', hideDefaultActions: true,}];
```

Elements for the expanded data:

```
const Grid_Exp_Rows = ['123556','123556-A' ];
```

The static data I got created by following the above example:

```
const Grid_Data = [{
name: '123556',
locations: 'Atlanta, GA'
_children: [
    {
        name: '123556-A',
        URLs: 'www........com'
    },
],
},
```

How to parse the data from the JS array and pass it to the lighting-tree-grid?

Comment: If your question is as simple as it sounds, you only need to read the docs of the component you are trying to use, in this case, lightning-tree-grid, these are the docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation

Comment: You can check one of sample use case here:- https://salesforcediaries.com/2022/01/21/lightning-tree-grid-with-input-search-functionality/